# sublime text 3 line numbers do not match same file opened in vi due to a mixture of newline styles

Tags: sublimetext3

Riddle me this:

1. Jenkins master running on linux
2. Using a mac, I download a jenkins log as plain text and save it
3. Using `grep -n` I obtain line numbers for my desired content
4. Using vi the line number corresponds to the correct line
5. Using sublime3 macos darwin edition, I see that the line is **NOT** the same content as reported by grep and vi

At line 6500 or so I see a mixture of newlines which vi /grep etc ignore and sublimeText processes as actual newlines skewing the content.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 557.1 kB^MSending
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of a log that does this?

Comment: really I can't.

Comment: @OdatNurd . I hunted down the point where the problem was and figured it out.  Thanks for the offer of assistance

Answer (score 0):

So, I see the following options:
- fix newlines by making a small change in sublime and saving
- fix newlines via command line
- teach sublime to handle newlines like vi does

The easiest is to make a 1 char change, save the file and then rerun grep etc as the newline adjustment will be made by sublime and all will be in sync